# Predicate Logic & Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

Hello future aspiring Mathematicians! May i seek some hints about logic questions please? Could anyone help me out? I just need some tips to get the ball rolling.

The question wants me to provide proof that it is true and explain my answer. Otherwise, provide counter example.

The question:

> Assume that $\exists x\,\forall y\,P(x,y)$ is True and that domain of discourse is nonempty. If the statement is true, explain your answer; otherwise, give a counter example.

From the question, we know that $\exists x\,\forall y\,P(x,y)$ means there is an $x$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true for every $y$.

So the question wants me to prove $\forall y\,\exists x\,\neg P(x,y)$ that it is true, otherwise provide a counter example.

How do i start to answer this question? Do i start by using rules of inferences to proof?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. If you cannot see a direct link between both, it is likely that you can find a counter-example.

Take for instance $P(x,y)$ to be a tautology (always true), like $x=x$.

Comment: Hi Zuy, thank you for taking time out of your day to help me out. I really appreciate it. What do you mean "This is wrong"? Is it the way i asked the question or something else?

Comment: @GT3000X The assertion $\forall y\exists x\neg P(x,y)$ is wrong in general undee assumption of the original assertion.

Comment: You meant false or wrong as in the question is asked incorrectly?

Comment: @GT3000X The question is fine. I just provide a counter-example.